# $(X_1+X_2+ X_3 + \cdots + X_n)^2 =$ $?$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, square-numbers

$(X_1+X_2+ X_3 + \cdots + X_n)^2 =$ $?$

with $X_i$'s $ \in \mathbb{R}$

Just from computing $(a+b+c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2ab + 2ac + 2bc$ I am guessing the general formula is:

$(x_1 + \cdots + x_n)^2 = x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2 + 2(x_1 x_2) + \cdots + 2(x_{n-1}x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n{(x_i)^2} + \sum_{i\not=j}{2(x_i)(x_j)}$

Can someone verify this?

EDIT: Sorry lots of edits but I think I have finally come to what I think the general form is!

Comment: Why do you require $X_i$ to be random? Seems extraneous to your true question

Comment: @jameselmore true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote is a little off, it must be either
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n{(x_i)^2} + \sum_{i <j}{2(x_i)(x_j)}$$
or
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n{(x_i)^2} + \sum_{i \neq j}{(x_i)(x_j)}$$

Comment: I was JUST about to type this up. But thank you, haha.

Comment: @DavidSouth, another thing you will need to know is that, when we call $X$ the column vector with your entries $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n,$ and $G$ the symmetric matrix with all entries equal to $1,$ then your expression is exactly $X^T G X.$ I'm not completely sure you've had a course in matrices, it helps when learning statistics...Yes, just checked, you had linear algebra questions up until June.